# How to Order MYSQL Results By Number of rows in a another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 Tables:

```
1 - cat
Id|category

2 - groups
Id|groupname|category
```

---

I want to sort the data from the **cat** table by the number of rows in the **category** (group) table.

For example in groups table, category row have the following data:

```
Education - 20
Fun - 50
Nature - 30
```

I wanna show cat as:

- Fun
- Nature
- Education

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just count the amount of rows in the one table and order your results by the resulting count?

```
SELECT
*,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM category WHERE category.cat_id=cat.id) as count
FROM cat
ORDER BY count DESC;
```

**Note** To get a better answer, you'll need to be more specific about your table structure and what you would like to achieve.